Blazor Navigating to a sub page does not work before navigating to the home page
Question
How do I get a sub page in blazer to render the same way the home page does the first time?
Background
I have created a demo application for myself using the Blazer template on GitHub. https://github.com/staticwebdev/blazor-starter
the project is largely unchanged, with the exception of some subpages I have started
/LuckyLuke
/Chess
/Programmer
these pages are accessed has sub pages off the main page e.g.
lukehammer.com/luckyluke
lukehammer.com/chess
lukehammer.com/programmer
however if somebody navigates directly to them without visiting the home page first the page fails to render or give any meaningful redirection.
so https://lukehammer.com works but https://lukehammer.com/chess will not work.
but if you go to https://lukehammer.com then to https://lukehammer.com/chess that will work.
Question restated with context
Is there a way to cause page https://lukehammer.com/chess to work with out having to go to https://lukehammer.com first?

note here is my source code if that helps https://github.com/lukehammer/LukeHammerWebsite

Just to have pointed it out, in case you are not aware: https://www.lukehammer.com/chess is reachable. [EDIT: Cannot format the link properly: please hover over it to see the full link]

Could this be helpful? https://www.thomsip.net/articles/redirect-to-www-using-blazor

As mentioned in the comments it seems to be an issue with your redirection of your hosting:
https://lukehammer.com brings you to https://www.lukehammer.com but
https://lukehammer.com/chess not to https://www.lukehammer.com/chess
While allready on the site it redirects you to the correct page, because you are using a relative link, in your app.
You probably have to enable the redirect without the www. prefix for your site aswell on your hosting provider.

OK this is interesting I would not have discovered this.
The WWW seems to be working, even with sub pages.

I hope it helps. I would say there is something small you have to adjust in your DSL Routing. Probably not redirecting to WWW instead vice versa: redirecting from WWW to without prefix :)

You need to fallback all your endpoints to the index.html page.
In azure using Static Web App we create this file in the root of the project:
staticwebapp.config.json
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html"
  }
}

In your current host provider may be a little different.
